How to Create a Formula Field with the Date Format DD/MM?
I'm new to Salesforce and want to create a birthday field in the Contacts object. How can I build a formula that uses the DD/MM format?

Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please take a minute to read How to Ask and perhaps take the [tour] before you [edit] your question to state what you have tried and where you are stuck.

You should start here, looking at the Date functions section, and then considering the String functions available for concatenation and padding.

If you're new to Salesforce, definitely start with Trailhead tutorials, the Salesforce channels on Youtube, and other web resoures.

also check out: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=platform.formula_examples_dates.htm&type=5

To create a formula field in the contact object follow the below steps:

Setup -> Object Manager -> Contact -> Fields & Relationships -> New.
Select Formula as the data type.
Enter the field name
Select the formula return type as Text.
Enter the formula as below:
  TEXT(DAY(Birthday)) & "/" & TEXT(MONTH(Birthday))


Click on the next button, and set the field level security.
Click on next and add the field to the page layout you want.
Then click on the Save button.

For more information refer to this:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=platform.formula_using_date_datetime.htm&type=5
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=platform.formula_examples_dates.htm&type=5
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=platform.customize_formulas.htm&type=5
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/point_click_business_logic/formula_fields


Thank you for your response! The first link was very helpful in clarifying the information.

Additionally, If you want ensure two digits values for day and month then (eg: 01/05 instead of 1/5) update the formula as:
IF(LEN(TEXT(DAY(Birthday))) = 1, "0" & TEXT(DAY(Birthday)), TEXT(DAY(Birthday))) &
"/" &
IF(LEN(TEXT(MONTH(Birthday))) = 1, "0" & TEXT(MONTH(Birthday)), TEXT(MONTH(Birthday)))


Thank you very much for the additional information!
